# Что означает ошибка retrofit при отправке запроса и как ее исправить?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Я хочу отправить на сервер массив чисел long, этот массив я получаю из адаптера `recyclerview` и дальше я хочу этот массив отправить на сервер. Но почему-то получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
for method APIService.delete_several_message
```

я так понял из ошибки что проблема в параметре 2, вот как этот параметр выглядит в интерфейсе:

```
Call<Delete_several_messages> delete_several_message(@Header("Authorization") String token, HashSet<Integer> k, @Query("type") int type);
```

вот класс созданный для этого процесса:

```
public class Delete_several_messages {
    @SerializedName("ids")
    @Expose
    private Set <Integer> [] ids;

    public Set <Integer> [] getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
}
```

и вот как я в главном классе все вызываю:

```
mAPIService.delete_several_message("Bearer " + a_token,checked,2).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

вот эта часть:

```
mAPIService.delete_several_message("Bearer " + a_token,checked,2)
```

выделена желтым, и там висит сообщение:
`unchecked call to .enqueue(CallBack<T>)...`

вызов происходит в методе который прикреплен к нажатию на кнопку:

```
private void deleteGroup(HashSet checked)
```

вот где и как прописан этот метод при нажатии на кнопку:

```
deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MessageCenter.this, String.valueOf(ListAdapter.getChecked()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                deleteGroup(ListAdapter.getChecked());
            }
        });
```

данный сет приходит из адаптера.

у меня честно говоря первый раз подобная проблема возникает, чаще всего запросы шлются нормально. В чем может проблема, кроме той что сидит перед компьютером?)

Comment: Второй параметр не помечен никакой аннотацией и ретрофит не знает что с ним делать, куда впихнуть. Подозреваю что Вы опять попутали привет с ответом. Что от Вас ждёт сервер и что должен вернуть в ответ?

Comment: от меня сервер ждет, что я ему в json скину массив id писем которые нужно удалить, в ответ просто придет уведомление что все ок, то есть никаких данных обратно идти не будет

Comment: То есть `Delete_several_messages`? А Вы что ему посылаете...

Comment: не понял вопроса) вы хотите сказать что у меня неправильно массив строится?

Comment: Дополните вопрос форматами запроса и ответа. Если Вы должны передать просто массив, а не массив в объекте  - попробуйте пометить второй параметр аннотацией `@Body`

Comment: @woesss, вылетело с криком - `Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body. for method APIService.delete_several_message` я так понимаю тег @Body нельзя использовать в этом случае

Comment: Аннотация у метода какая, `@Get(...)`? У GET-запроса не может быть тела. Тело можно передавать POST-запросом

Comment: я использую `@DELETE` для этой операции, не гет

Comment: Как послать DELETE с телом посмотрите пример в доках: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/HTTP.html

Comment: та я вот уже думаю что может я неправильно вытаскиваю из hashset при выборе чекбоксов, из того вопроса где вы мне помогали

Comment: Правильно-не правильно, но у Вас здесь в запросе проблема - он с телефона даже не уходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка означает, что все параметры метода API-интерфейса для Ретрофита должны быть помечены аннотациями, указывающими Ретрофиту что с этим параметром делать.

Из всего выясненного получаются такие коды, пробуйте:

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "your/path", hasBody = true)
Call<ResponseBody> delete_several_message(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Body Delete_several_messages k, @Query("type") int type);
```

---

```
private void deleteGroup(HashSet checked) {
    Delete_several_messages body = new Delete_several_messages(checked);
    mAPIService.delete_several_message("Bearer " + a_token, body, 2)
}
```

---

```
public class Delete_several_messages {

    @SerializedName("ids")
    @Expose
    private Set<Integer> ids;

    public Delete_several_messages(Set<Integer> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: все вроде работает так как нужно)) но теперь массив приходит пустой)

Comment: Приходит пустой на сервер или сразу из адаптера уже пустой?

Comment: то что на сервер идет я вижу что пустое, а вот из адаптера я не вижу что выходит, но допускаю что тоже пустое

Comment: я думаю что в адаптере проблема, потому-что главный класс вызывает метод адаптера для получения массива

Comment: Ну так выведите в лог или через дебаггер посмотрите - пустой / не пустой он в этом месте

Comment: пишет что пустой, хотя hashset я докидываю при выборе checkbox. странно честно говоря

Comment: Ну вопросом больше - вопросом меньше))) - задавайте новый и показывайте что Вы наделали.

Comment: сейчас покажу)))