# Проблема с передачей данных из адаптера в главный класс android

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть вопрос по этой тематике - [Что означает ошибка retrofit при отправке запроса и как ее исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890467/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-retrofit-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C/890517#comment1454169_890517). На данный момент у меня получается послать на сервер запрос с пустым массивом который должен вообще содержать id сообщений которые должны быть удалены. Вот что у меня есть в адаптере:

объявление моего hashset:

```
private static HashSet <Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
```

---

длительное нажатие на элемент списка для получения id элемента:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (message.isCan_delete()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                setEditMode();

                holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            set.add(message.getId());
                        } else {
                            set.remove(message.getId());
                        }

                        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                return true;
            }
        });
```

---

и вот метод который возвращает массив:

```
public static HashSet <Integer> getChecked() {
        return set;
    }
```

и дальше все делается как и в том вопросе который я привел. По логике должно все работать нормально, но почему-то я даже не могу увидеть в тосте добавление нового элемента в массив при выборе чекбокса. Я надеюсь что ошибка простая и лежит на поверхности, но я почему-то не могу понять где именно.

Comment: А зачем `setOnCheckedChangeListener` задавать внутри `onLongClick`?

Comment: потому что у меня он должен работать только после длительного нажатия, или можно его вынести за пределы? я просто хотел ввести ограничения какие-то, что-то типа ограничения пока не было длительного нажатия

Comment: Ок, можно и так. Некрасиво, но не критично. Второй вопрос: в методе `onCheckedChanged` есть ссылка на какой-то `message`. Уверены что в нужное время там будет нужное значение?

Comment: знаете у меня складывается впечатление что то что вы указали в своем предыдущем комментарии, некрасиво и критично))) вынес все за пределы метода, и вроде все работает, но у меня может быть такое что сейчас работает а потом нет))

Comment: Вот это и хуже всего. Код должен быть быть предсказуемый.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, тут я с вами полностью согласен, вроде как пытаешься его сделать предсказуемым но все-равно постоянно что-то вылезает

Comment: В лонг-клике ему однозначно не место - здесь он вешается только на айтем, по которому кликнули.

Comment: да я уже понял что протупил немного, теперь все работает так как нужно, осталось только с разметкой повозится, потому-что один виджет не хочет валить почему-то